# How and where to get 'key' and then use it in get_post_meta()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the get_post_meta($post-id, $key) method, but i run into some problem becuase I do not know the key name for the post. How can I get the key? This code is simply an example for the get_post_meta($post-id, $key) function...

```
<?php
$current_post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '$the_key_i_do_not_know');
?>
<html>
<div class="container">
<?php
echo $current_post_meta[0]; //This echoes the post-id of posts with the same key as $the_key_i_do_not_know.
?>
</div>
</html>
```

If you have a script or some sort of way of getting a post's all keys that would be great thanks!

Best regards, Ledung.

Answer (score 2):

You can use get_post_custom_keys in order to get all of the meta keys related to the post. It returns an array. Here's an example from codex:

```
<?php
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $value ) {
    $valuet = trim($value);
    if ( '_' == $valuet{0} )
        continue;
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
}
?>
```

And here's the link to the codex:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom_keys/

Comment: And what is the correct key you are searching for? If it's not in the array, then it's not attached to the post (do not exists)

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're doing it within the loop? If not, you should provide the ID of the post as a parameter for the function

Comment: I already have a get_post_meta($post_id, $key) function that is functional and i am trying to make a new one. This function have the key: "course_id" that cannot be found using your code. And when I use your code on the new code i only find the field names.

Comment: Before you can get the data from `get_post_meta($post_id, "course_id")` the metadata with the key "course_id" should be created for this post using `update_post_meta` function. The key **does not exists until** you create at least one value under it.

Comment: Moreover, the meta key exists only until it has at least one value assign, so if you delete all of the metadata under the post labeled by the key, such key would not be displayed by get_post_custom_keys nor by get_post_meta

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I am looking into this right now! :)

Comment: Hello again I am sure that your solution would have worked but I chose to get the post-ID by using myself of the fields within Wordpress to solve the problem. Thanks anyways for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The get_post_meta() function without a key, returns an array of all post meta for a specific post id:

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id());
print_r($post_meta); // Shows all post meta
```

See also: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: When using print_r I do see all the meta values but I do not see the correct key why can this be?